# Why is DBeaver trying random ports when trying to connect to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, ssh-tunnel, dbeaver

I have Cassandra running on a host that i can assess via SSH. When I want to connect with DBeaver, I am using the following connection settings:

Connection:

- Host/Port: localhost:9042

SSH-Tunnel

- Host/Port: my.remote.host:37938

On connect, I am getting the following error message:

```
 
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:35836 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:35836] Channel has been closed))
```

When I try again, I am getting the same error for a different port number:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:48799 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:48799] Channel has been closed))
```

I had this behavior with Version 3 of DBeaver and also now with the newest Version 4.0.4
Why doesn't DBeaver use the configured port number to connect but a random one?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with port 22, it works for me.

Does regular ssh on port 37938 working? Make sure the port is open. JMX can use these ports, so maybe you are interfering with it.

Which version of Cassandra you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Set your HOST ip of your server to rpc_address in cassandra.yaml and restart your cassandra service.

Ex : If your cluster IP is 10.40.60.23
then cassandra.yaml in /etc/cassandra/ folder, incase of Ubuntu :
rpc_address : 10.40.60.23